# Gzweb not load well my world

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have create the following world [C:\fakepath\road_drone_textures.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1473418331636978.world).

with gzclient Works perfectly but in Gzweb, when load the second lamp shows the following error:

[image: image description]

I has tried to solved it and I have edited gz3d.js adding a "if" to comprobate that link[0] exists (line 1613).

```
if (link[0])
        {        
        if (link[0].self_collide)
            {
                link[0].self_collide = this.trueOrFalse(stats.link[0].self_collide);
            }
            if (link[0].gravity)
            {
               link[0].gravity = this.trueOrFalse(stats.link[0].gravity);
            }
            if (link[0].kinematic)
            {
              link[0].kinematic = this.trueOrFalse(stats.link[0].kinematic);
            }
        }
      }
```

This is part of the function:  GZ3D.Gui.prototype.setModelStats = function(stats, action)
I don't know how this will affect to gzweb consistency but solved part of my problem:
[image: image description]

the problem now is that gzweb not shows the road. Any idea's as solve it?

Thaks, Aitor (JdeRobot Team)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14373/gzweb-not-load-well-my-world/) by [aitormf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2715/aitormf/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-09-09**:
Nice catch adding the `if` statement, it would be great if you could make a pull request to GzWeb with the fix.

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2016-09-09**:
+1 on making a pull request for this. Let us know if you want us to do it

**Comment by [aitormf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2715/aitormf/) on 2016-09-11**:
I have make a fork of the Project and a new branch to solved this bug but, I don`t see how do the pull request

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-09-12**:
From this page, you should be able to choose your branch with the fix and make a pull request. Thanks! https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/pull-requests/new

**Comment by [aitormf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2715/aitormf/) on 2016-09-13**:
I don't have access to create new pull request.
My User in bitbucket is aitormf

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-09-13**:
Oh sory for the trouble. I hink it works if you go to your repo page and click on create pull request?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-09-13**:
Oh sory for the trouble. I think it works if you go to your repo page and click on create pull request?

**Comment by [aitormf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2715/aitormf/) on 2016-09-21**:
Sorry for my late reply chapulina, I have done the pull request (#93)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/pull-requests/89/fix-rendering-roads/diff) to fix rendering roads.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aitormf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2715/aitormf/) on 2016-09-12**:
It works perfect, with this pull request gzweb shows all world,
thaks, Aitor (JdeRobot Team)